# Promote artifact to different path in target repo

Tags: artifactory

There is API command to promote artifacts from one repository to another but this means that path to artifacts will be replicated. Is there a simple way to change a path to files in a new directory? Or I need to use copy/move for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The promote option is used to actually promote artifacts from one state to another. For example from a snapshot state to staging and from staging to release. If all you want is to move the artifacts from one folder to another then yes, use the move/copy REST API (Or UI, up to you).